# How to get top 10 largest files along with size in MB using "find" command

Tags: shell, unix

I want to get the largest files along with sizes in MB, as I'm new to unix I searches in google and found this command

```
find . -type f -printf "%s : %p \n" | sort -nr | head -n 10
```

%s is giving the size of file in bytes, and by replacing it with %k size been converted to KB.

Is there any option that can convert the size of file in MB

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and easy way to do this would be to pipe the output to awk:

```
$ find . -type f -printf "%k : %p \n" | awk '{$1/=1024}1' | sort -nr | head -n 10
```

The first column is divided by 1024 and the `1` at the end is a shorthand for `{print}`, so each line is included in the output.